# How do I use a trained Theano artificial neural network on single examples?

Tags: theano, deep-learning, mnist

I have been following the `http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/` tutorial on how to train an ANN to classify the MNIST numbers. I am now at the "Convolutional Neural Networks" chapter. I want to use the trained network on single examples (MNIST images) and get the predictions. Is there a way to do that?

I have looked ahead in the tutorial and on google but can't find anything.

Thanks a lot in advance for any kind of help!

Comment: What code have you tried, what errors do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The material in the Theano tutorial in the earlier chapters, before reaching the Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN) chapter, give a good overview of how Theano works and some of the components the CNN sample code uses. It might be reasonable to assume that students reaching this point have developed their understanding of Theano sufficiently to figure out how to modify the code to extract the model's predictions. Here's a few hints.

The CNN's output layer, called `layer3`, is an instance of the `LogisticRegression` class, introduced in an earlier chapter.

The `LogisticRegression` class has an attribute called `y_pred`. The comments next to the code which assigns that attribute's values says

> symbolic description of how to compute prediction as class whose
>   probability is maximal

Looking for places where `y_pred` is used in the logistic regression sample will highlight a function called `predict()`. This does for the logistic regression sample what is desired of the CNN example.

If one follows the same approach, using `layer3.y_pred` as the output of a new Theano function, the model's predictions will become apparent.

Comment: Hi again. Have i understood this right? Because LeNetConvPoolLayer uses the batch_size in __init__ I can not use the same instance of the model for training and predicting. Witch means that I need to transfer the weights and biases to an new model with batch_size = 1 to predict one image at a time. And to do this I can use cPickle to temporary save the parameters.